# App is not Receiving location push service extension push if Precise location permission is off

Tags: ios, swift, location, location-services

Our application is not receiving the location push if Precise location permission is not given by user. We could not find any documentation that relate Precise Location with Location push service extension. Apple document is also not clear on this. if there is any documentation please let us know.

Went through apple documentation but could not find any relation between Location push service extension and Precise location permission.